# How to clone datatable in another table in another database with diferent ip

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv, openrowset

I need to clone tables in another database with different ip.
I cant use linkserver, I need create a php for this.

I tried to use openrowset but i have error.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14
> [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.
> [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )

This is my code

```
 $sql = "SELECT a.* FROM openrowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver={SQL SERVER}; Server=IP\MSSQLSERVER2017;UID=demo; PWD=demo;', 'select * from dbo.cursos') as a";


 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $con2, $sql);

  if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
   }
```

This is only for see if i can get the data.

I am sorry for my bad english

Comment: How do you know if this command is working on your server? You tested it with some other tool? I mean not in PHP

Comment: yes sql server management Studio, but i need this in php with this or something